# Range X-X lock on table with primary key value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with a primary key and clustered index. I am updating the table as below,

```
update MyTable1
set     
 SomeColumns = @SomeColums    
where     
  MyPkColumn=@MyPkColumn
```

I have another table with the same design where I delete records,

```
delete from MyTable2
where     
  MyPkColumn=@MyPkColumn
```

Now in my logs sometimes I see deadlocks as below,

```
1) Process1 has RangeX-X lock on MyTable1 and waiting for S-U lock on MyTable2.
2) Process2 has X lock on MyTable2 and waiting for RangeX-X lock on MyTable1.
```

Now, `MyTable1.MyPkColumn` is the primary key why there is `RangeX-X` lock?

**Update:** The dataType of the parameter is different from `MyPkColumn`(specifically `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR`).

**Update:** We are using default isolation level `READ COMMITTED`.

Comment: Can you provide the actual deadlock XML?  Do you have any nonclustered indexes on either of those tables with the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option enabled?  You might be running into a situation [like this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224581/deadlock-with-insert-and-delete) - although, since yours is an update, it might only apply if you're updating key columns.

Comment: Unfortunately, the logs are cleared now. I found using sp_readerrorlog. For now, I have changed the data type. There is only a primary clustered key and no non-clustered key.